# How to detect which server I am using in .bash_profile and apply settings accordingly

Tags: linux, bash

I have a few virtual machines running Fedora 20 and one NAS box from which the HOME directories are mounted on all VMs. It works great as users have to maintain one copy of git settings, VNC settings SSH keys and so on. The problem is that regardless of whichever VM they use they always use the same .bash_profile which references always the same .bashrc. I say it's a problem because I want to apply some settings in there on per user basis but only for one specific VM. To be specific I want to change umask for few users on one specific isolated server.

So I thought there must be a way to conditionally load some settings through .bash_profile depending on the IP/hostname of the server.

I thought, just like .bash_profile references .bashrc I could reference another file with this setting which only exists on the server it will affect. Not the other servers this reference would not be valid. This is not an elegant solution, it would throw errors.

I've tried googling this and the results usually point me to stackoverflow where somebody had a similar question but this time I couldn't find anything.

Does somebody have an idea how to solve this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It won't throw any errors if you first check that the file is in place.

Comment: `uname -n` gives you the name of the 'node' (machine, VM) on which the shell is run.  You can use that to condition your settings.  Whether this is a good idea is a separate discussion.  I like that `.bashrc` to be as small and tight as possible, and running `uname` in it wouldn't suit me, but I do similar things in `.profile` or `.bash_profile` (which is executed once, at login, or at least when a login shell is started).

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler, I guess I just needed a push in the right direction. I also discovered that I can check `$HOSTNAME` which gives me the same result as `uname -n`. I posted my final solution below.

Answer (score 4):

You can put your host specific commands in `.bashrc_myhostname` and source it if it exists:

```
[ -f "$HOME/.bashrc_$HOSTNAME" ] && . "$HOME/.bashrc_$HOSTNAME"
```

or you can hard code commands for certain hosts with an `if` or `case` statement:

```
if [ "$HOSTNAME" = "mytestserver" ]
then
  ulimit -c unlimited
fi
```

Comment: Thanks. Since I'm not yet so good with bash it took me a while to understand what it does. I ended up using a simple `if` statement and testing a variable with my target vm against `$HOSTNAME`. I'll post my code later on. Since I'm new I can't answer my questions straight away. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This problably should be placed in `.bashrc` not `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I tested and does what I want it to do.
Most of my users look into .bashrc while changing their aliases so to make sure it won't be accidentally altered I left in in .bash_profile

```
TargetVM="vm1.example.lan"

if [ "$TargetVM" = "$HOSTNAME" ]; then
        umask 077
else
        umask 027
fi
```

Comment: I don't think `“` is valid.

Comment: Not sure how `“` got there, I copied it from vim (working copy), thanks for pointing out.